# Xcode 4 : define a preprocessor macro in a dependent target

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, c-preprocessor, static-libraries

I have an app named *MyApp* which is linked to a static library *MyLibrary*
I've added the *MyLibrary* project to Xcode and added the *MyLibrary* target to *MyApp*'s target dependencies.
All this works fine, I can set breakpoints, and I'm pretty happy.

The thing is that I want a conditional log in the library :

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define  MYDebug(msg, ...) NSLog(@"\nDEBUG -> %@ \n(%s:%d)",[NSString stringWithFormat:msg, ## __VA_ARGS__], __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__LINE__);
#else
#   define MYDebug(msg, ...)
#endif
```

So I have two build configuration for my library :
- **Debug** has "DEBUG=1" in the target's build settings in "preprocessor macros"
- **Prod** has nothing

And the *MyLibrary* target is set to build with the Debug build configuration.

This works fine if I build the static library (.a), and include it in a project.
But if it is built by target dependency, it seems that DEBUG is not defined (MYDebug doesn't log anything).

I've also tried to set DEBUG=1 in *MyApp*'s build settings, but it doesn't work.

Is there something I missed, or another way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, somehow you have overlooked something - what you are trying to do is pretty basic and fundamental. What version of XCode are you using? Did you try to 'Clean' (Apple-Shift-k) your target?

Comment: XCode 4. Maybe it's basic, but I'm new to libraries development, and I'm confused because it works except when the library is built from another project, as a dependency. I'll try to clean but I doubt it will help.

Comment: I only mean that you are perfectly right to expect this to work with out problems. Cleaning often does help, so please let us know.

Comment: Nop, it didn't fix it...

Comment: I think the problem was that *MyLibrary* had two build configurations (Debug and Prod), and *MyApp* uses different build configurations (Build-Debug, Build-Prod). So building *MyApp* dit not enable the *MyLibrary* Debug config. I thought it should. So I added DEBUG=1 not only for the *MyApp* Debug config but for all build configs. This is not a very good solution, but this target is not used for development purpose, so it gets the job done. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8):

It should just be "DEBUG" instead of "DEBUG=1".  Also, to use a macro that needs an Object assignment (NSString, etc) you need to escape most of the characters like `@` and `"` etc..

Here is a screenshot of a working project of mine from xCode 4.1:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't see why DEBUG=1 won't work while DEBUG will. And regarding the escaping of the characters doesn't seem to be the issue either, as it works fine when I build the library